# JCIFS error jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC00000BB

Tags: java, android, jcifs

I use `jcifs.jar` on my Android project. It works well except I change the language to Turkish.It throw exception below.

```
W/System.err(18799): jcifs.smb.SmbException: 0xC00000BB

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:640)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doNetShareEnum(SmbFile.java:1897)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doShareEnum(SmbFile.java:1797)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doEnum(SmbFile.java:1739)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1712)

W/System.err(18799):    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.list(SmbFile.java:1609)
```

Anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, resolved by changing library to codelibs fork https://github.com/codelibs/jcifs

API slightly different but can be fixed in few minutes.

Comment: Tried using jcifs-2.1.34 from codelibs and the issue with Turkish lang still exist. Can you please share the changes in API made. I have tried to change new APIs and replaced deprecated but it doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed it myself.It's a bug of JCIFS and i have reported to Jcifs team.

Comment: Can you give a link to a bug?

Comment: Hi, please update your answer it doesn't have any useful information